# VirtualBox bridged interfaces do not work with bridged networking

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, bridge

I'm trying to use a virtual machine to bridge connections between the VirtualBox internal network and my host's network.

The purpose of this is to be able to firewall connections without having to configure the guests to use a specific gateway or proxy. This is part of some automated testing I'm doing.

My current setup looks like this:

`{Internet} <=> Host <=VBox Bridged-eth0=> Bridge VM <=eth1-Internal Network=> Internal VM`

Ubuntu 16.04 is the OS on the host and VMs.

`Bridge VM` has `eth0` and `eth1`. These two interfaces are bridged with bridge-utils. **The bridge works when I use NAT instead of Bridged networking**. By this, I mean I can ping Google from the `Internal VM` when `eth0` is `NAT`, but not when it is `Bridged`. In both modes I can get an IP with DHCP so (some?) broadcasts seem to work, but arp resolution does not (arp command returns empty after some time, route doesn't know the mac of the gateway).

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I'm assuming it's some limitation of the VirtualBox software network device? I'm hoping there's a way around this as I need to be able to access all the VMs from my host whilst still being able to block their connections with this `Bridge VM` as a transparent firewall.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed promiscuous mode to "Allow All" on all adapters and now it works. I don't know why I didn't try this the firs time; sleep does wonders.